# HashMap errors - containsKey, get

Tags: kotlin

Can anyone shed some light?

### Problem code:

```
protected var table = HashMap<Class<*>, Double>()

if (table.containsKey(object)) {
    value = table.get(object)
}
```

> containsKey(K):Boolean is deprecated. Map and Key have incompatible
>   types. upcast to Any? if you're sure

so I changed it to this:

```
if (table.containsKey(object as Any?)
```

which fixes the error, but is this what I should have done to fix it? or is there a better way?

also `.get(object)` has an error:

> Type inference failed. required: kotlin.Double found kotlin.Double?

same error message for this too:

```
val c = someObject.javaClass // pre j2k code: final Class<? extends SomeClass> c = someObject.getClass();
weight = weightingTable[c] <-- error here
```

I don't know what to do here

Comment: What is the type of `object`?

Comment: good question.. it's an Inner Class of a Java class I created (not `someClass`, let's call it `SomeClassWithAnInnerClass.InnerClass`)

Comment: Map.get returns a nullable value (doesn't matter if you've check contains) as there is no compiler guarantee that entry will be in the map. So type of value should be Double?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `containsKey` call is reported as an error because the type of the argument you pass to it does not match the type of the map key. Your map contains classes as keys, and you're trying to pass an object instance to it. Changing this to `object as Any?` is not a useful fix, because this call will compile but will always return false. What you need to do instead is to use `object.javaClass` to get the class of the object.

The `weightingTable[c]` call is reported as an error because the map does not necessarily contain a value for the key you're passing to it, so the result of the `[]` operation is nullable. You cannot assign a nullable value to a non-null variable without somehow handling the null case (using a check, an explicit non-null cast or some other option covered in [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)).

Comment: I don't quite understand why it is nullable, everywhere I declared the `Double` as `Double` not `Double?` .. `protected var weightingTable = HashMap<Class<*>, Double>()` and `var weight: Double`

Comment: I cheated and used `!!` so that I could retain the `Double` declarations (I did try `Double?` but that made the code even more messy since it didn't like my math and comparison operators when I did that, so right now my solution is to use `!!`)

Comment: As the answer explains, it is nullable because the map doesn't contain a value for every possible key. `[]` returns null when there is no value corresponding to the given key.

Comment: ah, that makes sense...I wasn't thinking straight because I was thinking abut what I was putting in, not how to check if ithe key doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

When doing:

```
myHashMap.get(object)
```

and getting:

```
Type inference failed. required: kotlin.Double found kotlin.Double?
```

even when you already checked with containsKey. You can solve it by using:

```
myHashMap.getOrElse(key) { defaultValue }
```